# Wordpress query only returns 1 result, but all with nonpaging = true

Tags: wordpress

Completely confused with this one.

If I add the nonpaging => true to the query, I get all the results. However, I wish to only have 4 displayed in this particular loop. If I use the post_per_page => 4, I only get one.

Worse, if I add in orderby => 'rand' I will get some number between 1-5.

What the hell is going on?!?!?

```
// WP_Query arguments
    $args = array (
        'post_type'              => array( 'bottin' ),
        'posts_per_page'         => 4,
    );

// The Query
    $bottin = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
    if ( $bottin->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $bottin->have_posts() ) {
            $bottin->the_post();

            $voir_plus = get_field('voir_plus');

        if ( !empty($voir_plus) ) {

            // Vars
            $link = get_the_permalink();
            $image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
            $name = get_the_title();
            $posttags = get_the_tags();

            echo '<a href="' . $link . '"><div class="elementor-row"><div class="elementor-col-50"><img src="' . $image_url . '" class="img-responsive" width="300"></div><div class="elementor-col-50 intervenant-info"><h6>' . $name . '</h6><p>';
            if ($posttags) {
              foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                echo $tag->name . ' '; 
              }
            }
            echo '</p></div></div></a>';
        }
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this, "paged" and you might need to check this out https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'bottin'
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'paged'          => $paged
);

$bottin = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
```